Moderator Appreciation; 1 Year Anniversary
It has been just over a full year since the results from our first moderator election came in. We had two new moderators elected last year and they have just finished their first full year.
I would like to give a big thanks to Becky and Tang Ho:

 

Thank you guys for all the hard work you do behind the scenes to keep the site running as smoothly as possible.
Congratulations on your shiny, new, golden Sheriff's badges.

Hahaha thanks!! (:  (Also, wow does time fly!)
